Does anyone know this movie or tv series with aliens?
I'm trying to find a movie that I saw on US television more than four years ago, and it was probably from the late '90s or early 2000s. I think there are three main people: a man, a woman, and a kid. My recollections are very vague. I think (not sure) that the movie has aliens. In one part of the movie, they are chased out of a government facility, maybe only the guy (not sure). Anyway, the ending of the movie has the three people at a warehouse and they are trying to do something with a satellite dish or something like that.  Also, there are ships or some kind of like black hole is pulling them in or they are being shot at by ships. I think it could be the black hole. Sorry I can barely remember it.

Sounds like They Live from John Carpenter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live

no that's not it its not that old

its not an old movie like 2000 or late late 90s

Was it American? Where\when did you see it? (And BTW, can you please use some punctuation? Most of your post is one big run-on sentence and it's hard to understand what's going on in it.)

It is American, I saw it more then 4 years ago, and it was just on TV

At least I think it is can't really remember it.

Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

I can't remember it, I think about it every now and then but still can't remember it.

The Arrival 1996 
About a astronomer discovers an extraterrestrial radio signal and get fired for reporting it, but he keeps searching and discovers that aliens are  disguising themselves among humans, so he try to expose\stop them with the help of his girlfriend and a young boy




not that one too old
